# numpy searchsorted multidimentional array by first column

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

I have got a numpy array like `numpy.array([[1,2,3],[3,2,1]........)`, I am trying to apply the `searchsorted` to find the indices of the first column.

```
A = numpy.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[2,2,3],[3,2,1]........)
B = [1,3]   #the search first column value
```

Expected output:

```
[0,3]
```

[`numpy.searchsorted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) has not documented the case in a multidimensional array. Would someone please suggest the most efficient way to resolve this matter?

Comment: `np.searchsorted(A[:,0], [1,3])` to search the sorted first column. The first parameter is limited to [*1-D array_like*](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html).

Comment: Thanks you, how about if the element is tuple type?

Comment: Can you add code how you would construct such a `numpy` array with `tuple` type? And your expected output? Fast answer would be: don't use `numpy` to sort collections of object type.

Comment: with specific each datatype of the element such as dtype = [('a',int), ('b',int)], this would produce the tuple